# Swift: Save CLPlacemark attribute value (read only issue)

Tags: swift, core-location, cllocation

I have a CLLocation object that I fill with a latitude and longitude and with that I am trying to get the zip code of that location, I have this function below called getLocation and when I print the "placeMark.postalCode!" value I do get a valid zip code, but when trying to save that value I have tried to create a string variable called location and set that value to the zip code, however it always is blank whenever I try to display it in my app. I have also tried to use a function that returns the value but it also does not work. Is it because when accessing these values they are only read-only?

```
var location : String = ""
var theLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

func getLocation(theLocation: CLLocation) {
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(theLocation, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        let placeArray = placemarks ?? []

        var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
        placeMark = placeArray[0]

        self.location = placeMark.postalCode!
    })
}
```

Comment: This code runs asynchronously.  When are and how are you checking the value of `location`?

Comment: This is inside of async operation so you need to ensure the self.location is updated on the main thread. E.g. 
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() { self.location = placeMark.postalCode! }`